# C# Excel VSTO: Difference between get_Range() and Range()

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am trying to understand the difference between Worksheet.Range() and Worksheet.get_Range(). Take the two lines of codes below:

```
Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].Range("A4").Value2 = "test";
```

This will print "test" on cell A4 on worksheet labelled "Sheet1". Similarly,

```
Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].get_Range("A4").Value2 = "test";
```

should produce the same result, instead I got:

```
'System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'get_Range
```

Can someone explain when and how to use get_Range()?

Is there any performance benefit?

Comment: A lot of the Office indexers return a value of type *object*, roughly equivalent to the .NET 1.x collection objects like ArrayList.  Which maps to __ComObject, the RCW for a COM interface.  It has no get_Range() method, only the strongly typed interface does.  Using Range invokes the late-bound property getter.  You'd have to cast to WorkSheet to use get_Range().  Which is not uncommon, breaking up such a long statement is desirable and many programmers like the IntelliSense hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# code, a property `X` produces methods named `get_X` and `set_X` under the hood. Therefore, `get_Range("A4")` should instead be written as `Range["A4"]`. See the code in the first example in [this MSDN document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59dhz064.aspx) for an example.

I doubt you will see any performance difference, though as in most performance questions the answer is "try it and compare times".